# Convert RenderTargetBitmap into System.Drawing.Image

Tags: c#, wpf, system.drawing, bitmapimage, rendertargetbitmap

I have 3D WPF visual that I want to pass into an Excel cell (via clipboard buffer).

With "normal" BMP images it works but I do not know how to convert a `RenderTargetBitmap`.

My code looks like this:

```
System.Windows.Media.Imaging.RenderTargetBitmap renderTarget = myParent.GetViewPortAsImage(DiagramSizeX, DiagramSizeY);
System.Windows.Controls.Image myImage = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
myImage.Source = renderTarget;

System.Drawing.Bitmap pg = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(DiagramSizeX, DiagramSizeY);
System.Drawing.Graphics gr = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(pg);
gr.DrawImage(myImage, 0, 0);

System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetDataObject(pg, true);
sheet.Paste(range);
```

My problem is that `gr.DrawImage` does not accept a `System.Windows.Controls.Image` or a `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.RenderTargetBitmap`; only a `System.Drawing.Image`.

How do I convert the `Controls.Image.Imaging.RenderTargetBitmap` into an `Image`, or are there any easier ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was the solution I came up with

```
System.Windows.Media.Imaging.RenderTargetBitmap renderTarget = myParent.GetViewPortAsImage(DiagramSizeX, DiagramSizeY);
System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapEncoder encoder = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.PngBitmapEncoder();
MemoryStream myStream = new MemoryStream();

encoder.Frames.Add(System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame.Create(renderTarget));
encoder.Save(myStream);
//
System.Drawing.Bitmap pg = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(DiagramSizeX, DiagramSizeY);
System.Drawing.Graphics gr = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(pg);
//
// Background
//
gr.FillRectangle(new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(BKGC), 0, 0, DiagramSizeX, DiagramSizeY);
//
gr.DrawImage(System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromStream(myStream), 0, 0);
System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetDataObject(pg, true);

sheet.Paste(range);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can copy the pixels from the `RenderTargetBitmap` directly into the pixel buffer of a new `Bitmap`. Note that I've assumed that your `RenderTargetBitmap` uses `PixelFormats.Pbrga32`, as use of any other pixel format will throw an exception from the constructor of `RenderTargetBitmap`.

```
var bitmap = new Bitmap(renderTarget.PixelWidth, renderTarget.PixelHeight,
    PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);

var bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bitmap.Size),
    ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat);

renderTarget.CopyPixels(Int32Rect.Empty, bitmapData.Scan0,
    bitmapData.Stride*bitmapData.Height, bitmapData.Stride);

bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand the question right, but you want to copy a RenderTargetBitmap to the clipboard, couldn't you just call SetImage ?:

```
    Dim iRT As RenderTargetBitmap = makeImage() //this is what you do to get the rendertargetbitmap
    If iRT Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Clipboard.SetImage(iRT)
```